# Why is "Authentication is required to ...?"

Tags: mount, 15.10, suspend, authentication, sd-card

When I plug an SD card into the SD card reader (`/dev/mmcblk0`), a popup appears, saying:

> Authentication is required to mount a device.

When I plug in a VGA cable between my laptop and an external monitor, I get:

> Authentication is required to create a colour managed device.

When I close the lid, requesting the computer suspend, I get:

> Authentication is required before suspending the system.

I've done everything suggested in the answers to:

- [Authentication required before suspend](https://askubuntu.com/questions/543921/authentication-required-before-suspend)
- [Stop asking for authentication to mount USB stick](https://askubuntu.com/questions/552503/stop-asking-for-authentication-to-mount-usb-stick)
- [Authentication required to Mount a Device](https://askubuntu.com/questions/158411/authentication-required-to-mount-a-device)

And rebooted, but the same results persist.

The latter two popups don't actually prevent anything from happening -- the screen still works, and so does suspension, but I can't access the SD card until I authenticate.

If only because they're an annoyance, how can I make them go away?

My user is definitely in the `sudo` group, and I've edited the `polkit` XML files as suggested in the above questions.

Is there some way to make these stop?

---

the output of `groups` is:

```
cat adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare libvirtd
```

Comment: @mchid I've edited my question -- should `admin` be in that list?

Comment: admin group is used for support of older versions of Ubuntu. It's useless as of now

Comment: Yes that list looks fine.

Comment: Do `stat /dev/mmcblk0` see what that tells you

Comment: @Serg `Access: (0660/brw-rw----)  Uid: (    0/    root)` ? -- If I add an entry to `/etc/fstab` to change that, then Ubuntu will complain if there is nothing mountable on that port at boot, and make me hit a key, which I do not want.

Comment: Does this help https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=102050 ? Although the thread is a bit old.

Comment: @mchid No, that doesn't help.

Comment: If you use fstab add the user,noauto options, user allows regular users to mount, noauto prevents mountall from trying to mount it at boot.

Comment: @MttJocy Ooh, interesting. That's one bullet gone.

Comment: Or just add yourself to the `disk` group. You might want the `dialout` and `audio` groups as well. I was actually going to mark this question as a duplicate of another, about how to make policykit not prompt you for passwords, but am unable to do so, due to the bounty.

Comment: @dobey Adding yourself to the `disk` group is a bad idea, as well as not actually fixing the root problem.

Comment: @dobey I've tried editing all the Polkit files, and it hasn't helped, which  I also mentioned in my question.

Comment: Have you tried adding the polkit configs to `/etc/polkit-1/rules.d/` as described [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Polkit#For_specific_actions)?

Comment: if you put yourself in the `root` group it'll probably stop asking... but that is bad practice as you'll basically be running every app with full perms

Comment: @wagyourtail That seems like a bad idea. This no longer affects me (I reinstalled) but I won't VTC since maybe it will happen to others and get answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you can get a Live CD / Live USB for the version of Ubuntu you're running, boot to it and select the "Refresh system files" option. This may reset some other changes you have made to system files.
2. For me, the problem went away when I `do-release-upgrade`d that system from 15.10 to 16.04 -- probably because the `polkit` infrastructure changed and so did the configuration causing the issues.

Unfortunately, I don't know of another way to fix this without Live Media or waiting for a version change.